# sql unique constraint with time window

Tags: sql, sql-server, unique-constraint, referential-integrity

I have a table where records have a (begin, end) time window of existence (for things like employement duration, birth and death, rent duration, ...)

begin IS NULL or end IS NULL if there is no bound.

```
CREATE TABLE mytable(
id int primary key,
value int, --UNIQUE at any point in time
begin datetime  NULL,
end datetime  NULL
);
```

I want column value to be unique at any point in time.

```
INSERT INTO mytable VALUES(1, 1, '2021-07-23', '2021-07-24'),(2, 1, '2021-07-25', NULL);
```

Is OK

Whereas

```
INSERT INTO mytable VALUES(1, 1, '2021-07-23', '2021-07-30'),(2, 1, '2021-07-25', NULL);
```

Is not OK, because both records have value=1 and overlapping time windows.

Is there a way to enforce such a constraint in SQL ?

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this on the table, no, as there's nothing to make `UNIQUE` on.
What you could do, however, is use a `VIEW` to enforce it.

Firstly, let's create your table. I assume the columns `datetime`, should actually be `begin` and `end`; I recommend against these names as they are reserved keywords. As such I am calling them `DateBegin` and `DateEnd`. I am also *assuming* that they are date only (no time portion) values and so define them as a `date` not a `datetime`:

```sql
CREATE TABLE dbo.mytable(ID int primary key,
                         Value int, 
                         [BeginDate] date NULL,
                         [EndEnd] date NULL);
```

And we'll `INSERT` your first 2 rows, as they are "ok":

```sql
INSERT INTO dbo.mytable (ID, Value, BeginDate, EndDate)
VALUES(1, 1, '20210723', '20210724'),
      (2, 1, '20210725', NULL);
```

Now we need to make a `VIEW`, but we need one row per date. As such you'll want to create a Calendar Table. I'm not going to cover how to create one here, but there are literally 100's of articles, such as there on SQL Server Central: [Bones of SQL - The Calendar Table](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/steps/bones-of-sql-the-calendar-table), [Calendar Tables in T-SQL](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/calendar-tables-in-t-sql).

Once you have your Calendar table, you can create the `VIEW` below, which `JOIN`s the data in your table to the calendar table. We're going to make it so that the `VIEW` just returns the columns `value` and the date. WE're also going to schemabind it; this means we'll be able to add an `UNIQUE INDEX` to it:

```sql
CREATE VIEW dbo.MyView
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
    SELECT MT.[Value],
           CT.CalendarDate
    FROM dbo.MyTable MT
         JOIN dbo.CalendarTable CT ON MT.BeginDate <= CT.CalendarDate --I assume, despite your schema, MT.BeginDate can't be NULL
                                  AND (MT.EndDate >= CT.CalendarDate OR MT.EndDate IS NULL);
```

Now we have a `VIEW` that has a row for each date, and for each value. This means we can now create our `UNIQUE INDEX`:

```sql
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX MyIndex ON dbo.MyView ([Value], CalendarDate);
```

Now if we try to `INSERT` a row that is on the same date and value, we'll get an error:

```sql
INSERT INTO dbo.MyTable (ID, Value, BeginDate, EndDate)
VALUES(3, 1, '20210720', '20210723');
```

> Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'dbo.MyView' with unique index 'MyIndex'. The duplicate key value is (1, 2021-07-23).